# How to get all JIRA notifications?

Tags: notifications, jira

We use JIRA 7.0.4.

I'm trying to work out the best way to get notified of any comments/changes/anything on a JIRA ticket. Do I need to be a Watcher? A Participant? The Assignee? Or is it reliant on whether or not the comment is @Budfudder?

I'm having a hard time finding any definitive statements on this in the JIRA documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Strange question. Notification that you receive depends on you permission browse issue and notification scheme in project settings. If you want recieve all notifications one of best practices this is create role named like Notificator and add all event to this role in notification scheme/browse permission in permission scheme.